# Typescript decorator: get class decorator value from method decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, reflect-metadata

I have a class decorator (fooAnnotation) and method decorator (barDecorator).

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

function fooAnnotation(value: string){
  console.log('fooAnnotation init...');
  return (target: any): void => {
    console.log('fooAnnotation called...');
    Reflect.defineMetadata('fooAnnotation', value, target);
  };
};

function barAnnotation(value: string){
  console.log('barAnnotation init...');
  return (target: any, propertyKey: any): void => {
    console.log('barAnnotation called...');
    Reflect.defineMetadata('barAnnotation', value, target);
    ...
    const fooAnnotationValue = Reflect.getMetadata('fooAnnotation', target);

   // :( fooAnnotationValue is undefined!!!
  };
};



@fooAnnotation('fooAnnotationValue')
class Foo{

 @barAnnotation('barAnnotationValue')
 public bar: string;
}
```

My need is that barAnnotation must use the value of fooAnnotation, but unfortunately typescript evaluates class decorators after method decorators, so inside barAnnotation the fooAnnotationMetadata is not defined yet.

How can a method decorator retrieve the value of class decorator?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Class Decorator` has been executed at the end of class declaration.  So, change your mind, you should store something in the property decorator, and process all in the class decorator.

```
const innerTempPropsName = '__TempProperties__';

function fooAnnotation(value: string){
  console.log('fooAnnotation init...');
  return (ctor: any): void => {
    console.log('fooAnnotation called...');
    Reflect.defineMetadata('fooAnnotation', value, target);
    const vProps = ctor[innerTempPropsName];
    // now process the vProps...
    delete ctor[innerTempPropsName];
  };
};

function barAnnotation(value: string){
  console.log('barAnnotation init...');
  return (ctorPrototype: any, propertyKey: any): void => {
    console.log('barAnnotation called...');
    const ctor = ctorPrototype.constructor;
    let vProps = ctor[innerTempPropsName];
    if (!vProps) ctor[innerTempPropsName] = vProps = {};
    // store temp properties into vProps
    // vProps[propertyKey] = {value, }
    Reflect.defineMetadata('barAnnotation', value, target);
    ...
  };
};



@fooAnnotation('fooAnnotationValue')
class Foo{

 @barAnnotation('barAnnotationValue')
 public bar: string;
}
```

Comment: thanks for solution but its not working somehow